# Strange function limit

Tags: limits

Can anyone show me how to evaluate this limit [image]

where $B>A>0$? If I try with some $A,B$ and give values to $n$, I discover that the limit is $B$ (the biggest number), but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{A^n+B^n}{A^{n-1}+B^{n-1}} = \frac{\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^n+1}{\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{B}}
\end{equation}
You know that $A/B<1$ so we have $(A/B)^n\to 0$, which gives you that the limit value is $B$ as you discovered before.

Comment: Yes!! It's really easy but the extrange function had confused me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you divide numerator and denominator by $B^{n-1}$, the terms in $A$ go to zero with increasing $n$